# URL routing on Bitnami Google Compute Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I am attempting to deploy the sample rails app: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4 to the Google Compute Engine using Bitnami. I have followed the wiki instructions to do so from: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Ruby_Stack#How_can_I_deploy_my_Rails_application.3f

But upon attempting to access the url for the site, it still does not direct to the Rails app
as you can see here: http://www.1234-ok-go.com (a domain I have purchased) it simply goes to the base Ruby Stack success page.

Even though I have setup the httpd-vhosts.conf to specifically target the Rails App:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 1234-ok-go.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/public"
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName 1234-ok-go.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/public"
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

How can this issue be alleviated and route the URL to my Rails app?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here.

After you had created your httpd-vhosts.conf (the one you pasted) file under `installdir/apps/myapp/conf/` you have to append this line to `/installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`

```
Include "/installdir/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

And then create this file: `/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf` to look something like this:

```
<Directory /installdir/apps/myapp/htdocs/public>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerAppRoot "/installdir/apps/myapp/htdocs"
</Directory>
```

And finally, restart apache:

```
<installdir>/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```